# Magento 2 grid column text alignment

Tags: magento2, grid

I tried to make a custom grid with column in magento 2 like this:

```
<column name="referral_code">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Referral Code</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

it shows successfully, but the text default alignment for `th` and `td` is left, how can i make it in center?

Answer (score 1):

**By default in UI grid data render from the left side**

[image]

Please add this line of code to align the data at  **center** on UI grid

```
     <item name="fieldClass" xsi:type="string">a-center</item>
```

[image]

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this.

```
<column name="referral_code">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">center</item> <!-- this is for align -->
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Referral Code</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
</column>
```

Answer (score 0):

When working exclusively with the ui-component, the correct config item argument is:

```xml
<column name="field">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            ...
            <item name="fieldClass" xsi:type="string">a-center</item>
            ...
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

See (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-column.html).

Comment: When I try to use this approach, I'm getting the `The XML in file "/magento/app/code/****.xml" is invalid: Element 'argument': This element is not expected` error. How to fix it?

Comment: Please share the XML block you're using so we can troubleshoot.